# Cannot edit "stack snippets" on SO

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I am using a FF 50 under Windows 10. Right now I don't have an access to another computer, so I can't figure it out myself.

Looking at whatever article I could find, Stack Snippets are still functional, and I come across them in answers quite often, but I don't understand how to *create* them! When I create/edit question or answer, I just don't have a "Create snippet" button like it's shown in the introduction [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Also, "edit the above snippet" button is not visible.

Is it only for users with some reputation, or is it environment related, or whatever ?

Answer (score 6):

this is actually working all fine; only the icon is different from what was presented on the screenshots, and as it looks so generic, I did not bother to check :((( My bad..

Thanks everyone

```js
alert("Forgive me pls");
```

Comment: Even though this ended up being a sort-of false alarm, it still points out that the introduction page needs to be updated. The little script-tag icon makes sense, once a person sees it, but it's so easy to overlook, and a diligent person who goes to find the  [authoritative source](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) should be rewarded with accurate information.